# How to show TableView Data on a new Window by clicking the data

Tags: javascript, json, titanium, tableview

I am creating an app which will show all user data in tableView
        which on click of particular record the full data of the user should 
        get displayed. The data is json object responce. i have tried the
        following code, it works perfectly till first table, records get 
        display in tabular format but when i click on the record it show an error. 
        i have have written the follwing code for these

```
var tableData = [];
var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView();
function srch() {
var client=Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
      onload: function(e){
      var obj=JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
      var deal, deals, row, nameLabel, skillkLabel ; 
      for(var i=0 ; i < obj.entities.length ; i++) { 
                    deal=obj.entities[i];
                    row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                        height : 'auto',
                        hasChild : true
                    });

                         nameLabel= Ti.UI.createLabel({
                            text : deal.name,
                            font : { fontSize : '16dp', fontWeight : 'bold'},
                            height : 'auto',
                            left : '10dp',
                            color : '#000',
                            top : '5dp',
                            touchEnabled: false
                         });            

                    skillkLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                            text : deal.skill,
                            font : { fontSize : '16dp'},
                            height : 'auto',
                            left : '150dp',
                            color : '#000',
                            bottom : '0dp',
                            touchEnabled: false
                         });    


                         row.add(nameLabel);
                         row.add(skillkLabel);
                         tableData.push(row);
                }

            tableView.setData(tableData);

            window2.add(tableView);
            window2.open();


    },
}
tableView.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 viewDetails(e.rowData.tableData);
});
function viewDetails(data) {
 var self =Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : '#fff',

 });

 var detailData = [];

  var detailTable= Ti.UI.createTableView();

 var detailRow =Ti.UI.createTableViewRow();

  var name= Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : data.nameLabel,
    top : '10dp',
    left : '10dp'
 });

 detailRow.add(name);

 var skill =Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : data.skillkLabel,
    top : '30dp',
    left : '10dp'
 });

 detailRow.add(skill);


 var city = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : data.city,
    top : '60dp',
    left : '10dp'
 });

 detailRow.add(city);



 detailData.push(detailRow);


 detailTable.setData(detailData);

 self.add(detailTable);
 self.open();
}
```

while executing the viewDetails() function , it gives an error that 
text : data.nameLabel, not defined. so can anyone help me guys.

*EDIT*
Here is the full error log:

```
[ERROR] : TiExceptionHandler: (main) [13953,13953] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error ----- 
[ERROR] : TiExceptionHandler: (main) [2,13955] - In app.js:566,15 
[ERROR] : TiExceptionHandler: (main) [35,13990] - Message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nameLabel' of undefined 
[ERROR] : TiExceptionHandler: (main) [2,13992] - Source: text : data.nameLabel, 
[ERROR] : V8Exception: Exception occurred at app.js:566: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nameLabel' of undefined
```

Comment: Please post your error log as well.

Comment: Error Log--
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [13953,13953] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [2,13955] - In app.js:566,15
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [35,13990] - Message: 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nameLabel' of undefined
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [2,13992] - Source:    text : data.nameLabel,
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at app.js:566: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nameLabel' of undefined

Comment: You should log your event e in the click eventlistener. Than have a look at e.rowData and e.rowData.tableData. At least one of these is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should access to the children of the row.

What you are doing is accessing to ***tableData*** that is not an attribute of row but just a variable you are using to store rows. Something useless in your case, as you assign the array of rows to the tableView inside the function *srch()* and probably you'll never use it again. So, you can move ***tableData*** variable inside ***srch***().

What it should look like is as below, try to print out what ***e.row()*** contains, and access to his children.

```
tableView.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(e.row));
  viewDetails(e.row);
});
function viewDetails(data) {
   var name = data.children[0].text;
   var skill = data.children[1].text;
}
```

I think what you are missing in here is that:

```
row.add(nameLabel);
```

name label is not an attribute of row, is just a variable (same for all the others). You can access just to *font, text, height etc*